# tipo de ponteiro incompatível

Tags: c, ponteiro

Olá, programando/estudando a linguagem, C, me deparei com o seguinte erro

```
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 int *ponteiro = &x;
```

Sendo o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){

int x[] = {0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7,8,9,10};
int *ponteiro = &x;

 for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
        printf("%i\n", *(ponteiro++));
    }
}
```

Como posso resolver esse erro ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você declara x[] x pode ser considerado como um ponteiro.
Quando faz:

```
int *ponteiro = &x;
```

na realidade está atribuindo o endereço do endereço.

Em seu caso faça:

```
int *ponteiro = x;
```